# Selenium IDE is not working with FF 56 anymore what other option I have

Tags: selenium-ide

I was using selenium IDE to generate testing scripts and use it in my web driver code. Now I cannot use it, it was useful because it automates most of the stuff for me, now I have to use XPath to do it myself. Is there any alternative to selenium IDE?

Answer (score 3):

Selenium IDE [has stopped working since Firefox 55](https://medium.com/@briananderson2209/in-search-of-the-selenium-ides-successor-33bc7eaefe7f). There are some workarounds, the quickest and safest way is to install [Firefox ESR](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/faq/) (until June 26, 2018).

Anyway, Selenium IDE is a legacy project dating back to the days of Selenium RC. The last time it got updated was in 2015. It will not work in other browsers, and new web technology is reducing its helpfulness.

You can refer this article for Selenium IDE alternatives for both Firefox and Chrome: [Top 3 Selenium IDE alternatives](https://www.katalon.com/resources-center/blog/selenium-ide-alternative-firefox-chrome/)